# How to remove html tags from word content?

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, office-interop

I know there are a couple threads about it which says simply using

```
Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```

but I cant use it in text written in word doc.
my code is like:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wBelge = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraf2;
paragraf2 = wBelge.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
paragraf2.Range.Text ="some long text";
```

I can change with finding and replacing like

```
Word.Find findObject = oWord.Selection.Find;
findObject.ClearFormatting();
findObject.Text = "<strong>";
findObject.Replacement.Text = "";
findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();               

object replaceAllc = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
findObject.Execute(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref replaceAllc, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Do I need to do this for every html tag?

Comment: If regex fails (I don't understand why it fails, can you show how you have used it?), you can create a list of all tags and using a for loop remove all the tags.

Comment: @Transcendent, he is dealing with a Word.Document object, not with plain text strings...

Comment: @elgonzo: yeah but those paragraphs can be converted to basic strings then regex works! aren't I right ?

Comment: I am not a user of Microsoft.Office.Interop, but i would suggest using a search pattern like `\<*\>` (or `\</*\>` for closing tags) in your Word.Find object. You will need to enable *MatchWildcards* to make the search pattern work...

Comment: @Transcendent, and what with all the formats/paragraphs/whatever things in the document? This will be lost if you convert it to basic text strings...

Comment: @elgonzo: yeah that's right, that is the side effect.

Comment: @elgonzo: Anyway, he's removing the tags, means that he wants to lose the format on purpose, so conversion to string wouldn't be a problem, would it ?

Comment: @Transcendent, i guess he is talking about HTML tags in his document content (as part of the text), and not about OOXML...

Comment: @elgonzo: Wow, how could I possibly not see that in the title :D

Comment: @Transcendent, don't mind. It's the famous "weekend state of mind". I am in that state regularly ;)

Comment: To remove everything between **<** and **>** use `\<[^>]*\>`.

Comment: @Transcendent I dont want to lose formats. First I do bold between strong tags and make red in span style:red tags. Now I want to remove them all

Comment: @elgonzo thanks for the advice. I tried                                         findObject.ClearFormatting(); findObject.Text = "<*>";                   findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();    findObject.MatchWildcards=true;                      findObject.Replacement.Text = "";                but It removes everything because sometimes text start with <strong> and ends with </strong>

Comment: You forgot the **backslashes** in the pattern. Use the pattern string `@"\<*\>"` (the @ is important here, otherwise you would need to write "\\<*\\>" in your source code) "<" and ">" are special wildcard characters indicating start and end of a word. But we do not want that here and treat "<" and ">" as normal characters in the pattern, hence the backslashes are needed in front of them. (You can also experiment with the pattern in Word's Find dialog - the Word.Find object should just work the same as the Find dialog, i guess...)

Comment: @elgonzo thanks! Write this as an answer please.

Comment: Actually, i would suggest you answering your own question Why? First, you have already the working code and you only need to copy'n'paste it into the answer together with a little explanation. Second, and more importantly, by doing so you are (hopefully) getting some more reputation (which is required to "unlock" certain features here; for example, you can only enter chat on SO when you have 20 or more reputation points). Third (and the most honest reason), i am a lazy bum... :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help provided in the comments, i realized the following working solution

```
findObject.ClearFormatting();
findObject.Text = @"\<*\>";
findObject.MatchWildcards=true;                     
findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
findObject.Replacement.Text = "";                       

object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
findObject.Execute(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref replaceAll, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

which is using the search pattern `\<*\>` (containing the wildcard character `*`, hence *findObject.MatchWildcards* must be set to *true*).

Answer (score 0):

Give a try the following:

Convert the text with HTML addings to a simple string using

```
string unFormatted = paragrapf2.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
```

and then replace the paragraf2 contect with the unFormatted string.

Comment: thanks but after I make bold the texts between strong tags, no matter I change in paragraf2.range.text it doesnt change the word document

Comment: @ruqo, I would like to understand properly: you have formatted text that you want to replace with unformatted text?